# How can I used Advanced Filter to find exact match?

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I am trying to understand how to find only exact matches within an Advanced Filter. For example, in the code below my range "filter" includes "Ford" and "Ford Escort" and when filtering on "Ford" I return on the values for "Ford Escort". Is there way I can return values only exactly matching "Ford"?

```
pl.Range("myNamedRange").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=fl.Range("filter"), copytorange:=hd.Range("A1")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem given the limited information you have provided. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and imagine that I cannot see what is on your worksheet!

Answer (score 1):

Not according to the docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter).

I'd just use autofilter and copy the visible cells: `pl.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`